# Adding cells to existing PDF via FPDI class

Tags: php, tcpdf, fpdi

I am trying to add a cell to an existing PDF, but unfortunately the document is a scan, which interprets it as one layer - a photo - I think so.
 
When adding a cell to such a file, I only have borderless text and no cell fill color on the visible layer of the document.

Am I in any way controlling the layers of the file in such a way that the cell being added is always the top layer and is fully visible?

Method to get existing PDF:

```
protected function getOldPDF()
{
    $pdf = new Fpdi();
    $pdf->SetCreator('Test');
    $pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
    $pdf->setPrintFooter(false);
    $pdf->SetMargins(0, 0);

    $numPages = $pdf->setSourceFile($this->filePath);

    for($pageNum = 1; $pageNum <= $numPages; $pageNum++) {
        $tpl = $pdf->importPage($pageNum);
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $pdf->useTemplate($tpl);
    }

    return $pdf;
}
```

I add cells with `TCPDF::MultiCell()`

Comment: Did you tried the [`setPageMark()`](https://tcpdf.org/docs/srcdoc/TCPDF/class-TCPDF/#_setPageMark) method after calling `useTemplate()`?